# Auto trigger button click of website on WKWebview Swift

Tags: html, ios, reactjs, swift, wkwebview

I have a website https://resorts.international, I would like to show the login screen from this website on WKWebView by trigger the Sign In button automatically. When I use the WKWebview to load this website, I can not get the `button class="navButtonLink"`. I will appreciate with any ideas/ solution to trigger this action without user action. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following WKWebView delegate method will help you, when you post a message from HTML page(SignIn) as `window.webkit.messageHandlers.submit.postMessage('ACTION_NAME');`

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController:WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if(message.name == "ACTION_NAME") {
           print("triggered")
        }
}
```

Hope the WKWebView navDelegate delegate is set.